# Inserting document to mongo DB causes error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node js program, and I am trying to insert a new document to the collection through my API:

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res) {

    var apple = {
      name: req.body.name,
      ip: req.body.ip
    }

    serverSchema.insert(apple, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('added');
      }
    });
});
```

The schema looks like this:

```
var serverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // unique + required do not allow duplicates in the dbs 
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  ip: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('serverSchema', serverSchema);
```

However, when I try to add this item I get the following error thrown:

```
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model)) {
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    }
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'insert'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

*The dbs connection is open

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `serverSchema` incorrectly.  There is no `insert` method for a `mongoose.schema`.

Schema file looks something like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://000.0.0.1/test');

var serverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
     type: String,
     unique: true,
     required: true
   },
   ip: {
     type: String,
     unique: true,
     required: true
   }
});

module.exports = db.model('server', serverSchema)
```

API file looks something like this:

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res) {

    //require mongoose model defines in model/serverSchema.js
    var aServer = require("./model/serverSchema");

    var apple = new aServer({name: "Honeycrisp", ip: "red"});

    post.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return err;
      } else {
        console.log('added');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: so how can I insert a document?